# Is use of mmap'ed memory thread safe in linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, mmap

I want to share a variable between two process and also access it multi thread.

Do i need to use mutex while accessing this mapped variable
with following flags

```
PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS
```

Comment: What is the variable exactly?  And what platform are you on?

Comment: Variable is integer and arm9 platform

Comment: Your question title is misleading. It seems you are not asking whether the call to `mmap` is thread safe. But whether you need synchronisation on memory `mmap` returns. The answer to the latter is YES. Memory received from `mmap` is not special in that regards. If there can be simultaneous reads/writes then you need synchronisation.

Comment: @kaylum: that comment is and should be  an answer. I edited the title, although there is probably a better way of phrasing it.

Comment: @kaylum : the mutex should be process shared ?